# Могу ли я добавить в документ страницы свой тип узла?

Tags: javascript

Возможно это глупо, но я начинающий, и хотел использовать инструменты ООП.

Точнее, хотел добавить узлу дополнительное поведение создав класс-потомок оригинального узла, и определив некоторые свойства и расширив новыми методами и добавить в документ.

Но ничего не получается.
Возможен ли такой ход, вообще?

```
function MyNode(){
    this.className = "my_node"
}
MyNode.prototype = document.createElement("div");
MyNode.prototype.myMethod = function(){
    // some
};

document.body.appendChild(new MyNode());
```

Что я хотел сделать?
Есть какой-то класс нод, с общим поведением и параметрами.
Создавать их надо таким образом:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.className = "my_node";
node.добавляетТекст = function(текст){
    this.innerHTML = текст;
};
node.добавляетТекст("Я твоя совесть");
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

То есть если следовать принципам ооп, я должен бы выделить такие ноды в общий класс. То есть это не новый тип тегов(я хоть и непротив, но подозреваю, что могут быть проблемы с совместимостью, хотя это было бы, пожалуй более правильно), а просто определение нового поведения только для создаваемых объектов, js это позволяет.

Comment: добавь минимальный пример того что ты пытался сделать. Возможно тебе нужны [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: Добавил, спасибо.

Comment: В будущем будет возможен, но сейчас поддержка таких выкрутасов браузерами довольно плохая

Comment: Вообще наследоваться никто не мешает. Просто создать нужный элемент не получится, по крайней мере пока, потому что нет типов html элементов, есть только интерфейсы, и их нельзя создать вызвав конструктор.

Comment: И еще большой вопрос, нужно ли здесь наследование, или лучше просто хранить в поле ссылку на нужный элемент

Comment: Ну, если нельзя, то напишите в ответе. Я отмечу как правильный. Желательно, конечно, если с каким-то альтернативным решением, но необязятельно.

Comment: для альтернативного решения нужно понять что именно ты хотел этим наследованием добиться. Если в примере в вопросе убрать `MyNode` и использовать сразу `document.createElement("div")` - то ничего не поменяется, только заработает

Comment: Я хотел добавить начальные параметры и поведение созданным объектам.

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _поведением_? Обработчики событий?

Comment: @Grundy обработчики добавлять тоже хороший вариант. Обновил шапку, для тебя.

Comment: А мне кажется что автор спрашивает как открыть бутылку пива об курок заряженного ружья. Объясните что в итоге Вы хотите сделать? Просто поймите, здесь много очень умных людей, но  они как дети отвечают на все что их спрашивают, умалчивая о том, что они бы так не сделали. Поэтому лучше расскажите что Вы хотите, только подробнее.

Comment: @OlmerDale, я ничего не говорю. Буквально пару дней js изучаю.

Comment: @Grundy, вы всё верно сказали. Есть только веб-компоненты, которые ещё не реализованы нигде. Написали бы в ответ.

Comment: @Grundy, типы в js5, кстати есть. Например HTMLDivElement. Всё упирается в интерфейс appendChild, он отказывается добавлять кастомные классы.

Comment: HTMLDivElement - Это Interface. его можно указать в качестве родителя, но как я выше сказал - создать при этом экземпляр наследника будет проблематично. Веб-компоненты частично поддерживаются

Comment: Я уже и веб-компоненты попробовал, но не пошло. Ни один пример не заработал.